# Problems With Hair Particles

Tags: particles, hair, particle-nodes

So I'm working with my model and I decided it should probably have some hair on the side. So I do the whole weight paint thing and added hair in that area, so then I created the hair and combed it down shown here:
[image]

Alright, so that's ok. But when I go to Object Mode:
[image]
I don't want to have to redo the whole thing but if it must happen it must, any suggestions?

Comment: Does it also look that messed up without children?

Comment: Yes, it has children and it looks like that.

Comment: @MicahVera I think you didn't understand Blunder's question right...please read again

Comment: Sorry, when I remove Children it calms down but the hair doesn't appear in the correct areas. It protrudes in any area it wants to around the model.

Comment: Looks like particle settings are ok and there is something wrong with the mesh geometry then. Are there modifiers on the emitter object/head? Subdivision, armature?

Comment: I did some subdivisions. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I discovered that the reason why the hair looked significantly different than the particle editor was that when I went to solid view I was later in the timeline and I had **Hair Dynamics** enabled. Therefore the hair went all over the place. Just make sure your timeline is at 0 or 1 when you work with this stuff, OK?